# I need a slicer which should show date range for last 3 months, last 6 months, last 9 months, and last 12 months in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, data-science, dax, data-analysis, business-intelligence

In power BI, I need a **Slicer** that shows date_range for **last 3, 6, 9, and 12 months** from the present date.

I tried creating a DAX Column using `Switch` and also with `If`, but the problem is it is not showing the correct data, can anyone help me with a DAX solution for this.

Comment: Do you want your data from the last 3, 6, 9, and 12 months of data or just the dates after selecting from a slicer?

Comment: No I want visuals to show the last 9 months data when I select for last 9 months that on slicer and resp. for others.
Please have a look on the image of the slicer I need, its uploaded on my drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t5oXwoklXrb_1d92EIXepawbEyIKrtSh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I  know how to create a visual for the last N no. of months of data and created on your visual too, but I don't know how to display it for the variable N no. of months :(. I'll let you know I get any success.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new separated table containing two columns. First with only Label "Last 3","Last 6" ... Second column "DateFrom" should contain data (first date of certain range), you can use SWITCH (if lable = X, then "First day of "Last 3 month").

So you can put Label on Slicer and use "DateFrom" in your measures as

```
Calendar[Date] >= SELECTEDVALUE(SupportTable[DateFrom])
```

EDIT:

My dummy model:
[image]

As you can see, there is no relationship;
Here is my Table with label:

[image]

```
DateFrom = SWITCH( TRUE(),
Range[DateRange] = "Last 12 months", DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()) -12, 1),
Range[DateRange]= "Last 6 months", DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()) -6, 1),
Range[DateRange] = "Last 9 months", DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()) -9, 1),
Range[DateRange] = "Last 3 months", DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()) -3, 1),
TODAY()
)
```

Now the main. I put my Calendar into a table (still no relationships) and my dummy measure (to show only that it filters data). Main part is to use SELECTEDVALUE

```
CountDays = CALCULATE( count(Query1[Calendar[issue_date]]]),CALCULATETABLE(Query1,FILTER(ALL(Query1), SELECTEDVALUE(Query1[Calendar[issue_date]]]) >= SELECTEDVALUE(Range[DateFrom]) && SELECTEDVALUE(Query1[Calendar[issue_date]]]) < TODAY() )))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm new at this but not sure if this will work for what I need
Have a look on the slicer I want it's on my drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t5oXwoklXrb_1d92EIXepawbEyIKrtSh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey! 
I'm still stuck, I followed your steps I created the range table successfully, But I want all my visuals to get affected by the selection on slicer, I've uploaded the .PBIX file can you please help! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rm2zVSuhpJXS9F6mBxS6x2i59EBGVMrN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: msta42a Thanks you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

it is a bit tricky to solve your question, and Power BI doesn't support this directly, but I still have implemented this in Power BI.:

Here are my steps to solve the problem, accept the answer if helping :)

1. Create a measure for counting the `BRAND_NAME` and  `SHPMT_SU`. The DAX is as follows:

`M1 = COUNT(Sheet1[BRAND_NAME])` and `M2 = COUNT(Sheet1[SHPMT_SU])`

2. Create a `Date Table` with the following columns.

[image: Date table]

2. Create another `Date Table` as:

`PreviousDate = 'Date'`

3. Create a relationship between the `Date` Table and `Sheet1`.

[image: Relationship model]

4. Create a measure that will show the last 12 months of data by default. You can change this by changing the variable value in the DAX.

```
   M1 | Last 12 months =
   VAR MaxDate =
   MAX ( 'Date'[Date] )
   VAR NoMonths = 12
   VAR SelectedDate =
       EOMONTH ( MaxDate, - NoMonths )
   VAR MaxDate_13MonthsAgo =
       EOMONTH ( MaxDate, - SelectedDate )
   VAR Result =
       IF (
           HASONEVALUE ( PreviousDate[YYYYMM] )
               && MAX ( PreviousDate[Date] ) <= MaxDate
               && MIN ( PreviousDate[Date] ) > MaxDate_13MonthsAgo,
           CALCULATE (
               [M1],
               FILTER (
                   ALL ( 'Date'[Month], 'Date'[Year], 'Date'[YYYYMM] ),
                   'Date'[Month] = VALUES ( PreviousDate[Month] )
                       && 'Date'[Year] = VALUES ( PreviousDate[Year] )
               )
           ),
           BLANK ()
       )
   RETURN
       Result
```

[image: Measure formula]

5. Repeat step 4 for Measure `M2` too by changing the DAX formula.
6. Now in the `Date` table create a calculated column as:

```
    VAR monthDiff =
        ( YEAR ( TODAY () ) - YEAR ( 'Date'[Date] ) ) * 12
            + MONTH ( TODAY () )
            - MONTH ( 'Date'[Date] )
    RETURN
        IF ( monthDiff < 4, "Last 3 Month" )
```

7. Repeat step 6 for the `Last 6 Month`, `Last 9 Month`, and `Last 12 Month`. It will give you the following `Date` table and 'PreviousDate` table.

[image: Date Table]

8. Create the visual with the measure `M1 | Last 12 months` from `Sheet1` and `Date` from the `PreviousDate` table.

[image: Visual]

9. Create a button slicer by setting the orientation to Horizontal and drag the `Month Class 3` column from the `Date` table not from the `PreviousDate` into the slicer. Make sure to select only non-blank values.
10. Create 3 more slicers with the other Month Class columns.

[image: All slicers]

11. By default last 12 months of data.

[image: Last 12 months]

Last 9 months of data.

[image: 9months]

Last 6 months of data

[image: 6monthsofdata]

Comment: Hey! Thankyou so much for your efforts, it definitely gives me the way :)

Comment: Thanks. If you need the video link for creating trailing data just let me know. Also, please considering upvoting and accepting the answer if it helps you.